# Homotopy vs Conservative

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, multivariable-calculus, algebraic-topology

I learned about conservative fields in multivariable calculus. I'm always curious about finding other or more fundamental methods of describing a concept (or concepts) in math, and better understanding how these methods relate.

Question: To what extent and in what ways do "homotopy" and the concept of conservative relate?

Mini question about terminology: In regards to homotopy and conservative, can each term be used to describe functions, fields, or both functions and fields? (Specific kinds of functions or fields? e.g. flux field)

Answer (score 5):

A homotopy is a continuous deformation of a map or object, usually a path in this setting. In a conservative vector field, changing a path by a homotopy does not change the value of a path integral over that path. The opposite is also true; if homotopies do not change the path integral, the field is conservative.

If you're looking for deeper insights on the connection between differential vector fields and topology, you should look up de Rham cohomology, which shows that a lot of the most important topological information about a space comes from differential forms on that space.